# Attaching multiple click events without having to repeat myself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mofny/0czhs1ko/1/).
Ignore the styling, that's not important.

Basically I needed to open the Fancybox with two links present, but I only want one gallery image.  I figured that out easily enough.  When the thumbnail is clicked it triggers the li anchor.
To keep the galleries separate I did unique classes for each ol.

The problem I have run into is I will be repeating myself.
I attempted to do a loop (commented out), but the logic is beyond my grasp.

What is the best way to attach a new click handler (I need to add 8 more) without repeating myself in my current fashion?  I've also tried a function with a couple parameters, but I had trouble with the `e.preventDefault()`.

I greatly appreciate any guidance, thanks!

Comment: I'm not seeing any js in this fiddle...?

Comment: Why not adding an event to a class, then apply this class to all elements you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a great use case to use jQuery's `on()` method. `on()` is a method that will allow you to establish a handler on an outer container that can listen to its children for click events. So, for example: if you specified a class of `.js-listen` on your lists, you could call `on()` like this:

```
$('.js-listen').on('click', 'other-selector', function(e){
   // function logic with either $(this) or e.target goes here
}
```

This block would essentially look for all elements with `.js-listen` and then when something inside the element with the `.js-listen` class is clicked, the event will bubble up through the DOM and the event will be handled according to the element that was clicked. The second parameter I have `'other-selector'` can be a class name, element, or ID. so you could essentially put something like `img` there and it would fire the event if the child element clicked was an `<img>` tag.

This prevents you from attaching a handler a million times, and one of the benefits of `on()` is that if elements are dynamically added to the container with the handler, you don't have to worry about attaching handlers to those elements, because again, they bubble up!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok I'm getting there: http://jsfiddle.net/mofny/0czhs1ko/99/.  As you can see it is still a little buggy.

Comment: Not too bad, although I think you misunderstood part of my explanation, I see you're gathering all the `activateThumb` classes with `$('.activateThumb');`, What I'm suggesting is that you take all of the elements with this class, and wrap it all in a single div, maybe something like `<div class="activateThumbArray"></div>` so you can call the listener like this: `$('.activateThumbArray').on('click', '.activateThumb', function(){
 // logic
})`

Comment: That way when stuff INSIDE that div is clicked, the handler will check to see if the thing clicked was an `.activateThumb` :)

Comment: How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/mofny/0czhs1ko/111/  Still not quite what I wanted.

Comment: What behavior are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Click on a thumbnail and it should open that thumbnail.  For some reason in each new year (2001, 2002, 2003) the thumbnail's indexes start at 0.  Shouldn't the fourth image on the page have an index of 3 instead of 0?

Comment: Click on the first thumbnail after the first ol.  The wrong image appears in the lightbox.  It gives me an index of 0, when it should be 3 because that's the overall index of that class on the page.

Comment: I get very close when I remove another div wrapper.  I see what you are saying about the event bubble.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. And I suggest that you get this working with a single instance of a collection instead of trying it with four of them. You rely heavily on making sure the index lines up, I would maybe apply a data-attribute for an index number in the image and trigger a click on the corresponding `<a>` element through getting the index from the image with jQuery's `attr`. This conversation is getting a little too long, but I suggest you just attack a small subset of this first, that way you can reuse the code and make minimal modifications.